# Can we perform Load Test of Guidewire Application using Microfocus Load Runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, guidewire, microfocus

We need to Test Performance Load Test for Guidewire Application(version upgrade project). Can any one tell us that Load Runner supports Performance load test of Guidewire Application or not.
Pros and cons if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, LoadRunner supports architecturally the interfaces available inside of guidewire as well as the ability to monitor the infrastructure that Guidewire runs on.

Pros:   It's been there, done that, collected the T Short before.   It is a single point to exercise the interface, collect resource records, analyze the results, and report out the findings.

Comment: Thanks James for this valuable information.             

Also could you please tell us other than load runner which will be the best Jmeter or Gatling?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are comparing a tool which throws load in Jmeter or Gatling to a tool which throws load, monitors, analyzes and reports.  All of the open source tools are partial solutions.  And as partial solutions with no path to value by themselves they are all pretty much equal.

Align your testing to business risk.  You're testing in the insurance industry.  Slowdowns and outages are orders of magnitude mores costly than a commercial testing tool.